# FineUploader deleting with servlets

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I am quite new to this topic and this is my first time using FineUploader. I am currently using a Servlet to handle client requests and it works perfectly fine for "POST" but not for delete. The doDelete method in my servlet is never being called. Am I missing something here ?

```
    var manualUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
element : document.getElementById('fine-uploader-manual-trigger'),
                    template : 'qq-template-manual-trigger',
                    request : {
                    endpoint : 'UploadServlet',                                     
                    filenameParam : 'filename',
                    },
                    deleteFile : {
                    enabled : true,                                     
                    endpoint : 'UploadServlet', 
                    method : 'DELETE'           
                    forceConfirm : true,
                    },                      
                    thumbnails : {
                    placeholders : {
                    waitingPath : 'fine-uploader/placeholders/waiting-generic.png',
                    notAvailablePath : 'fine-uploader/placeholders/not_available-generic.png'
                    }
                    },
                autoUpload : false,
                debug : true
                            });
```

The console output :

```
fine-uploader.js:3961 DELETE http://localhost:8081/test/UploadServlet/0036839e-3f58-466b-a6d3-05b3f66cedda? 403 (Forbidden)
fine-uploader.js:257 [Fine Uploader 5.9.0] DELETE request for 0 has failed -    response code 403 fine-uploader.js:257
fine-uploader.js:257 [Fine Uploader 5.9.0] Delete request for 'file.png' has failed.
```

Comment: The issue is with your server, not with Fine Uploader. You'll need to figure out what on your server is rejecting the request, and why.

Comment: @RayNicholus . Thank you for your answer. I also thought so but I cannot understand why the server would "accept" the post request but not the delete one.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code for delete file option.

```
deleteFile: {
       enabled: true,
       endpoint: "UploadServlet",
       forceConfirm: true,
       params: {
       foo: "bar"
       }
}
```

Comment: I get the same error code : the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)...

Comment: The issue is with your server, not with Fine Uploader. You'll need to figure out what on your server is rejecting the request, and why.